# How to make an inner-bordered table in angular material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to make a table with angular-material, like this:

```
<div class="xo-container" layout="column"  layout-align="center center">
    <div layout="row">
        <div class="cell" flex="33">1</div>
        <div class="cell" flex="33">2</div>
        <div class="cell" flex>3</div>
    </div>

    <div layout="row">
        <div class="cell" flex="33">1</div>
        <div class="cell" flex="33">2</div>
        <div class="cell" flex>3</div>
    </div>

    <div layout="row">
        <div class="cell" flex="33">1</div>
        <div class="cell" flex="33">2</div>
        <div class="cell" flex>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i want to be seen just inner borders of this structure. How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to define three row class as `first-row`, `row` and `last-row` for top and bottom border and three `cell` class as `first-cell` , `cell` and `last-cell` for left and right side border.

CSS file

```
div.first-row div{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div.row div{
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
}

div.last-row div{
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

div.first-cell {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}

div.cell {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}

div.last-cell {
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML File

```
<div layout="column" flex style='background-color:red'>
 <span flex="10"></span>
<div layout="row" class="first-row">
    <div class="first-cell" flex="33">Content 1</div>
    <div class="cell" flex="33">Content 2</div>
    <div class="last-cell" flex>Content 3</div>
</div>

<div layout="row">
    <div class="first-cell" flex="33">Content 11</div>
    <div class="cell" flex="33">Content 22</div>
    <div class="last-cell" flex>Content 33</div>
</div>

<div layout="row" class="last-row">
    <div class="first-cell" flex="33">Content 111</div>
    <div class="cell" flex="33">Content 222</div>
    <div class="last-cell" flex>Content 333</div>
</div>
```

Here is working example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/PNxxyR